# Getting the required output in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue in getting the required output for below scenario.

```
name | provider  | visit_dt    | rd | rn  
 A   | 100000    | 06/05/'17   | 1  |  1
 A   | 100001    | 06/04/'17   | 1  |  0
 A   | 100001    | 06/03/'17   | 1  |  0
 B   | 100000    | 06/05/'17   | 1  |  0
 B   | 100001    | 06/05/'17   | 1  |  1
 C   | 100000    | 06/05/'17   | 1  |  0
 C   | 100001    | 06/04/'17   | 1  |  0
 C   | 100001    | 06/03/'17   | 1  |  1
 D   | 100001    | 06/05/'17   | 1  |  0
 D   | 100001    | 06/04/'17   | 1  |  0
```

There are 4 different scenarios here:

1. If the most recent has rd = 1 and rn = 1 then pull the most recent visit(person A)
2. Get the most recent visit for each person with rn = 1 (person C)
3. If rn = 0, then pull the most recent RD (person D)
4. If both the visits for a person are with different providers on the same date, then pull both the providers irrespective of rd and rn values (person B)

So the expected output should be as below.

```
name | provider  | visit_dt    | rd | rn
A    | 100000    | 06/05/'17   | 1  |  1
B    | 100000    | 06/05/'17   | 1  |  0
B    | 100001    | 06/05/'17   | 1  |  1
C    | 100001    | 06/03/'17   | 1  |  1
D    | 100001    | 06/05/'17   | 1  |  0
```

It would be great if anyone could help me to solve this issue.

Any suggestion would be appreciable.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is visit_dt a date/time? or text?  Please clarify #3, it looks to me like B would be a correct response as well.  Will each name have at least two rows in all cases?

Comment: Yes, visit_dt data type is  date.. rest of the columns are varchar.Each name should be showing up only once in the output but the person B will be twice with same visit date but with different provider.

Answer (score 1):

If this is SQL 2008+, I believe this will work (as long as visit_dt is a date datatype).

```
WITH cte1 AS (
  SELECT name, provider, visit_dt, rd, rn, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY visit_dt DESC) AS thisrow
  FROM t
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte1 
WHERE thisrow =1
```

http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=1dc1bf626aed520d601fe68f1f11be55

Comment: Actually, I think it may get the correct results by pure dumb luck. I'll step through it to make sure it catches all of your rules.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. With this , am able to get the person B in the output with both the providers. But , for person C, the most recent visit is being pulled instead of the visit with the rn = 1. I tried using     SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (  PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY RD+ RN DESC,VISIT_DT DESC) AS R       
    FROM A                                                                     WHERE R=1   This gave me all the abve mentiond scenarios but it was missing one of the records of the person B with 2 providers on same visit dates . Could u pls help me in anyother way?

Comment: @Mamtha C is proving to be problematic. If I exclude anything not the results of C, it eliminates some of the other valid results. The other results methods will include the first record of C. The problem with the C rule is that the other rules include results from C that aren't supposed to be matched. I thought that 1 and 4 conflicted, but they more overlap. I still can't get the logic of Rule 2 to match up without breaking the logic from the others. My solution above does seem to handle Rules 1, 3 and 4, but not 2. Can you verify again that those rules are what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some contradictory conditions here is my approach:

```
Select * from (
    Select *, Con1 = Row_Number() over(Partition by [name] order by visit_dt desc) ,
            Con2 = Row_Number() over(partition by [name],[rn] order by visit_dt desc)
    from yourVisits
    ) a
    Where  (a.Con1 = 1 and rd =1 and rn = 1)
        or (a.Con2 = 1 and rn=1)
        or (a.Con2 = 1 and rn=0)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.. But this is missing the person B with 2 providers. Its giving only one record for this 'If both the visits for a person are with different providers on the same date, then pull both the providers irrespective of rd and rn values (person B)'. Would you please mind helping me in any way to get this too in my output?

Comment: @Mamtha Yes, some of these conditions can conflict, ie 1 and 4. What happens if a person has a 2 latest visits on one day, but one visit is rn=1,rd=1 and the other is rn=0, rd=1? Do we pick both or just the 1/1 record?

Comment: Looking at your expected results, it does appear that we would return both. So the 1/1 would be picked up by Rule 1, and the 1/0 would be picked up by Rule 4. Correct?

Comment: And Person C doesn't pick up the latest visit because there is a 1/1 record. Is that the correct flow? Is a person excluded if they already have a higher match? Or is that a faulty test?